# remove subdocument in array with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

Hi I have an entry like this in my database: [database entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkNUq.png) and want to remove a subdocument from the wishlist, ex: 222223. I have tried doing so with the following code:

```
async removeProduct(visitorID: number, productID: number) {
    const product = await this.visitorModel.findOne({ visitorID: visitorID });
    console.log(product);
    
    product.updateOne({
        $pull: {
            wishlist: productID
        }
    }, { new: true })
    

    console.log(product);
}
```

When I try to make an delete request I get the following result printed with my console.logs:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6228c61d0f4a800664f46eb5"),
  visitorID: 2122323,
  wishlist: [ 222223, 22222, 22222 ],
  __v: 2
}
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6228c61d0f4a800664f46eb5"),
  visitorID: 2122323,
  wishlist: [ 222223, 22222, 22222 ],
  __v: 2
}
```

its like it doesn't find the entry "222223" from the wishlist array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing is happening is because you are not telling mongoose to *execute* your request.

When calling `findOne()`, `updateOne()`, `deleteMany()` or any other method related to your mongoose model, what you get is only a `Query`. If you want it to be executed you need to use `await` or the `exec()` method.

And that's what you did when you called your model's `findOne(...)` method. You just forgot to put an `await` before `product.updateOne(...)`.